# Determine if an ASP.NET ListBox Item is Selected Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have the following function which will iterate through *all* of the items in my ASP.NET `ListBox` upon being clicked:

```
$('#<%=MyListBox.ClientID %>').children("option").each(function () {

}
```

I do not want this function above to change because for the outer function I need to loop through *all* items to process some logic. However internally I need to see if the item in focus is selected or not and can't get it correct. I've searched a ton of posts that can make the function only return selected items, but I want a check to see if the current item in this function is checked.

I tried:

```
if ($(this).selected())
```

...and that threw an error stating `object not supported`. I also tried:

```
if ($(this).selected == true)
```

...and it said `selected` was undefined, yet when I look at `$(this)` the value of `selected` is `false`.

How can I check within my function to see if the current item in the loop is `selected`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out in how to determine if the `option` value is selected. I used the `prop()` [method from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) as shown below:

```
$('#<%=MyListBox.ClientID %>').children("option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('selected'))
    {
       //Do work here for only elements that are selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.selected) /* ... */
```

Should suffice, if not then `this` doesn't refer to what you're thinking it does.

[If the `option` doesn't have a `selected` attribute, then you'll get `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected) -- as the property doesn't exist. Thus, `this.selected` will work; as `undefined` is **falsey**.

Note - you're receiving appropriate error messages for both scenarios you've described.

```
if ($(this).selected()) /* there is no method `selected` for this
                           jQuery object */

if($(this).selected == true) /* selected will be undefined for option's that
                                don't have a selected attribute */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R6KA8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
ddlListItems is the Id of the Listbox

```
$('#ddlListItems option:selected').text() != '' ? alert("Item is selected") : alert("No Item selected");
```